# ERROR: Call to a member function get() on null

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, slim

**INDEX.PHP**

> Esta es mi funcion de index.php la cual me debe recibir las fechas que se escogen en una tabla determinada (fecha desde y fecha hasta) siempre termino recibiendo este error

```
$app->get('/filtro/fechas', function() use ($app) {
$response = array();
$db = new DbHandler();
$fecha1 = !empty($app->request->get('fecha1')) ? $app->request()->get('fecha1') : date("d-m-Y");
$fecha2 = !empty($app->request->get('fecha2')) ? $app->request()->get('fecha2') : date("d-m-Y");
$resultado = $db->getOrdenesByFecha($fecha1, $fecha2);

$response["error"] = false;
$response["Ordenes"] = $resultado;
return $responseJ->withJson($response);
```

});

**dbHandler.php**

```
public function getOrdenesByFecha($fecha1 = false, $fecha2= false){
$response = array();
$fecha1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fecha1));
$fecha2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fecha2));

$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id from orden 
WHERE inicio_traslado BETWEEN ? AND ? && estado = 'PENDIENTE");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $fecha1, $fecha2);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $res = $this->getOrdenById($row["id"]);
    if ($res == RECORD_DOES_NOT_EXIST) continue;
    else $response[] = $res;
}
return $response;
```

}

Comment: No sé si es por la consulta que devuelve `null`, te falta una comilla simple para `PENDIENTE`. Ponlo así: `$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id from orden 
WHERE inicio_traslado BETWEEN ? AND ? && estado = 'PENDIENTE'");`

Comment: tus claves para autenticarte con tu base de datos son correctas?